# Bootstrap is not loading Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

Can someone help what is wrong with the object here?
Bootstrap is not loading in the html page (Thymeleaf)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkIS1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if it has access to the bootstrap css file and also try using bootstrap cdn.